# Seaborn clustermap: what's the main argument, observations or distances?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, seaborn, hierarchical-clustering

What's the *data* argument for [seaborn clustermap](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html).

Does it take a matrix where each cell is the distance between the vectors of the original matrix with observations? Or the clustermap calculates the distance itself so that I need to pass the observation matrix?

In the first case, what the argument *metric* is there for? Is there to indicate which metric has been used to calculate the distances?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38858404/1628638) of mine gives details of the distance calculation in `clustermap()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously - look at the ''examples'' on the very page you linked - it expects a *data* table, and a metric to use for computing distances.

As the documentation of clustermap clearly states, it uses
[scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)
to compute pairwise distances.

I do not seen an option to use a precomputed distance matrix, although it may be possible to pass a custom function that could do a matrix lookup.

Comment: Then there is something that I don't understand, why in the example where the the cluster is retrieved calculating a cosine metric we have a scale between 0 and 600? Isn't the cosine bound between -1 and 1? What am I missing?

Comment: The color is not the distance, but the input data.